# static fields in Utility class

Tags: java, android

folks! I am quite a newbie in Android development and in development in general.
I work on an app, that should show rounded bitmaps. I've created a utility class that looks like this:

```
public class PictureClipper {

    private static Bitmap before;
    private static Bitmap after;
    private static RoundedBitmapDrawable img;

    public static RoundedBitmapDrawable makeItRound (String baseImage, Resources resources){
        byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(baseImage.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        before = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        if (before.getWidth() >= before.getHeight()){
            after = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    before,
                    before.getWidth()/2 - before.getHeight()/2,
                    0,
                    before.getHeight(),
                    before.getHeight()
            );
        }else{
            after = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    before,
                    0,
                    before.getHeight()/2 - before.getWidth()/2,
                    before.getWidth(),
                    before.getWidth()
            );
        }
        img = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, after);
        img.setCircular(true);
        return img;
    }
}
```

I thought that by not creating a new object inside the method and by reusing class fields, I might optimize a bit.
But recently I got into reading open-source code (to improve myself) and was surprised to find almost the exact same implementation, but the objects were created inside the method. The app is called LeafPic and here is the code:

```
public class BitmapUtils {
    public static Bitmap addWhiteBorder(Bitmap bmp, int borderSize) {
        Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
        return bmpWithBorder;
    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap srcBmp){
        Bitmap dstBmp;
        if (srcBmp.getWidth() >= srcBmp.getHeight()){
            dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp,
                    srcBmp.getWidth()/2 - srcBmp.getHeight()/2, 0,
                    srcBmp.getHeight(), srcBmp.getHeight()
            );
        } else {
            dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp, 0,
                    srcBmp.getHeight()/2 - srcBmp.getWidth()/2,
                    srcBmp.getWidth(), srcBmp.getWidth()
            );
        }
        return dstBmp;
    }
}
```

Sadly, I have no clear idea if there is any difference and, in case there is, how to measure it. Can anyone clear it for me?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: *"I thought that by not creating a new object inside the method and by reusing class fields, I might optimize a bit."* - **Never** choose a certain syntax or construct for performance considerations *unless* you  really have a performance problem *and* you have **proven by measurement** that the chosen variant really solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference is: your code, that uses **static** fields isn't thread safe. As soon as you have **more** than one thread invoking `makeItRound()` chances are that the multiple threads start **overwriting** the static fields `before` and `after`.

The second piece of code does **not** have that problem.

In other words: you can invoke **static** methods in parallel as often as you want - but as soon as such methods are operating on **shared** data, your code is subject to multi-threading issues. And by using such static fields exactly that happens.